# Jenkins DSL, Get "stage logs" as list and print the failures

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am working with Jenkis [DSL]
Do you know a Jenkins API  to get all the logs of the JOB?

For example, there is a method to get console output:

```
def x = currentBuild.getRawBuild().getLog()
```

If there is an API, is it possible to convert the stage logs to a list and print the error log where the stage failed (red color)?

[The desired process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mON1.png)

I am trying to print the relevant error and not all console outputs like

```
def x = currentBuild.getRawBuild().getLog()
println (x)
```